# How to push progress to the repository even if the feauture isn't finished yet?

Tags: git

Lets say I'm working on some new feature for my imaginary application. I'm using a Desktop PC located at my workplace. It's five o'clock in the evening, so I get ready to head home. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to finish that feature but I want to work from home tomorrow.

What is the "proper" way to push progress (not a finished feature) to the repository?
And if your answer is that this is not what Git is made for, then how do you get around this problem?

Comment: This is exactly what branches are for.  Branches are cheap, branches are easy to make, branches are easy to merge or squash into single commits.  IMO Git was designed to make this easy, it's much harder to do this in older systems (like SVN or CVS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called **feature branch**.

You make a small branch just for the feature you are working on, then you commit as you go. Since nobody knows about the feature branch, you will not mess up anything by commiting unfinished stuff. You can push this branch to server; others will see it, but it will stay aside of everything. Also you can do `git commit --amend` as much as you wish, since noboy is supposed to use that branch anyway.

Once the feature is finished, you can use `git rebase -i` to clean up the history (e.g. get rid of commits with tiny fixes). Then merge the feature branch into `master` (or send merge request) and delete it.

**Hint:** `git push origin +feature_branch`. Use plus, not `-f`, as it won't overwrite anything else than specified branch.